# Is there a common shorthand for the $n^{\text{th}}$ antiderivative of a function?

Tags: integration, derivatives, notation, soft-question

The antiderivative of a function $f(x)$ is commonly written as $F(x)$. $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative is commonly written as $f^{(n)}(x)$. Is there something for the $n^{\text{th}}$ antiderivative?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I don't think there is an widely established notation for this. The reasons is likely that we very often bump into $n$th derivatives (Taylor series etc), but very rarely have to deal with $n$th anti-derivatives.

Comment: Perhaps, $f^{(-n)}(x)$ (the "($-n$)th derivative of $f$")?

Comment: One notation that is frequently used in undergraduate differential equations courses is the differential operator $[D^k]f$ to denote the $k$th derivative of $f$ and the notation $[\varphi(D)]f$ where $\varphi$ is a rational function (of polynomials). So, it was pretty common to use $D^{-k}$ for integer $k\ge 1$ to denote integration. I think it might be minor abuse of notation but it makes the work simpler to write: as an example $\left[\dfrac 1{1-D^2}\right]f=g$ would mean the function $g$ such that $[1-D^2]g=f$ or that $g-g''=f$. Alternatively, you may prefer to use $\int^{(k)}$

Comment: An advantage of the above notation is that algebraic manipulations like $\left[\dfrac 1{1-D^2}\right]f\equiv\left[\dfrac 1{(1-D)(1+D)}\right]f\equiv \left[\left(\text{id}-\frac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\right)\circ \left(\text{id}+\frac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\right)\right]^{-1}f$ make sense.

Comment: Note that, there is no one anti derivative due to the constant term which turns into a polynomial when you repeatedly antiderive.

Comment: An alternative that avoids notation for the sake of notation (which often does more damage than help) is to say "let $F$ be so that $F^{(n)} = f$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [differential operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator) notation it is often written as:
$$D^nf$$
Although often I also see it written as:
$$f^{(n)}$$
But I find this notation can be slightly ambiguous as it could be confused with things like:
$$f^{-1}\tag{inverse function}$$
$$f^n\tag{nth power}$$
I think if in the context differential operators are not used then the most unambiguous would be:
$$\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\right)^n$$
$$\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n}$$

For antiderivatives I think $D^{-n}$ or $f^{(-n)}$ would suffice

---

One final thought would be to define:
$$I=D^{-1}$$
then say:
$$I^n$$